# Apollo useQuery() - "refetch" is ignored if the response is the same

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

I am trying to use Apollo-client to pull my users info and stuck with this problem:

I have this `Container` component responsible for pulling the user's data (not authentication) once it is rendered. User may be logged in or not, the query returns either `viewer = null` or `viewer = {...usersProps}`.

Container makes the request `const { data, refetch } = useQuery<Viewer>(VIEWER);`, successfully receives the response and saves it in the `data` property that I use to read `.viewer` from and set it as my current user.

Then the user can log-out, once they do that I clear the `Container`'s user property `setUser(undefined)` (not showed in the code below, not important).

The problem occurred when I try to re-login: Call of `refetch` triggers the `graphql` http request but since it returns the same data that was returned during the previous initial login - `useQuery()` ignores it and does not update `data`. Well, technically there could not be an update, the data is the same. So my code `setUser(viewer);` does not getting executed for second time and user stucks on the login page.

```
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery<Viewer>(VIEWER);

  const viewer = data && data.viewer;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewer) {
      setUser(viewer);
    }

  }, [ viewer ]);
```

That query with the same response ignore almost makes sense, so I tried different approach, with callbacks:

```
  const { refetch } = useQuery<Viewer>(VIEWER, {
    onCompleted: data => {
      if (data.viewer) {
        setUser(data.viewer);
      }
    }
  });
```

Here I would totally expect Apollo to call the `onCompleted` callback, with the same data or not... but it does not do that. So I am kinda stuck with this - how do I make Apollo to react on my query's `refetch` so I could re-populate `user` in my `Container`'s state?

Answer (score 2):

This is a scenario where apollo's caches come handy. 
Client

```
import { resolvers, typeDefs } from './resolvers';

let cache = new InMemoryCache()
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
    headers: {
      authorization: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
  }),
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

cache.writeData({
  data: {
    isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
    cartItems: [],
  },
})
```

LoginPage

```
const IS_LOGGED_IN = gql`
  query IsUserLoggedIn {
    isLoggedIn @client
  }
`;

function IsLoggedIn() {
  const { data } = useQuery(IS_LOGGED_IN);
  return data.isLoggedIn ? <Pages /> : <Login />;
}
```

onLogin

```
function Login() {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(LOGIN_QUERY);
  let viewer = data && data.viewer
  if (viewer){
    localStorage.setItem('token',viewer.token)
  }
  // rest of the stuff
}
```

onLogout

```
onLogout={() => {
        client.writeData({ data: { isLoggedIn: false } });
        localStorage.clear();
      }}
```

For more information regarding management of local state. Check [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/) out.

Hope this helps!